# Strip html that is not in tags

Tags: php, text, preg-replace

I'm currently scraping a website and have all the useful data I need, although it comes with a bit of data that I don't want.

Example:

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>Useful <a href="/foo">data</a></p>
Rubbish <a href="/bar">data</a>
<h2>heading</h2>
```

So essentially I want to remove all text that is not enclosed by either `h2` or `p` tags.

Is there an easy function/preg?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Which class you are using for parse HTML ?

Comment: its a quick and dirty preg up to this point. (a quick and dirty hack project). Could use htmlpurifier but would rather not if I can help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are alittle better:

```
preg_match_all('~<h2>.*?<\/h2>|<p>.*?<\/p>~i', $str, $new);
```

Answer (score 1):

The laziest solution would be using phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) with just:

```
foreach (qp($html)->find("body *") as $node) {
    echo $node->html(), "\n";
}
```

It iterates over all tags below body, and skips text nodes implicitely. So you just have to collect the resulting ->html() snippets.

Comment: phpQuery is the bomb for web scraping.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do it is with PHP's DOMDocument class.  This is very similar to [mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998245/strip-html-that-is-not-in-tags/4998331#4998331), except that it doesn't require a whole new library.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<root>' . $yourContent . '</root>');

$nodes = $doc->firstChild->childNodes;

$output = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    if ($node->nodeType !== XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        $output .= $doc->saveXML($node);
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: As I said, it's just laziness :]

Comment: @mario Nothing wrong with that. Not including a whole new library could be considered laziness!